# Add parameter to datatable ajax call before draw

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10

Does anyone know how to dynamically add a parameter to the ajax call before table.draw() so my request has new parameters? I've looked everywhere and cannot find an answer.

I have buttons that a person can press and based on that button send different parameters to the server.

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: false,
        bLengthChange: false,
        bProcessing: true,
        paging: true,
         ajax: {
            url: me.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache:false,
            type: 'GET',
            data: function ( d ) {
                $.extend( d, me.data);
                d.supersearch = $('.my-filter').val();
            }
        },
        columns: me.columns,
        columnDefs: me.renderer,
        initComplete: function() {

        }
    });
```

This all works fine but then I try to tie it to a button to pass new parameters.

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
      var table  = $('#mytable').DataTable();
      table.ajax.params({name: 'test'}); <- I want to do something like this
      table.draw(); 
})
```

Comment: Why not use `$_GET` on the call?  Send the parameter in the `$_GET` to the server, and the server processes accordingly.  It is hard to tell what you are asking without a code example.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question, I'm trying to figure out how to send the parameter to the server after the table is initialized.

Comment: Again, please provide some .js code for how you are initializing the dataTable.  Also, it seems like you are using the legacy dataTables; you will find the newer dataTables easier to use.

Comment: I added my code, the top code works perfect, it's trying to send new parameters on click that is the issue.

Comment: The `data: function ( d )` part is confusing -- according to the jQuery manual it should not even work. What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's right in the manual: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have modified your code to do what you need.

**Initialize a data table:**

```
 $('#mytable').DataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bProcessing: true,
    paging: true,
    ajax: {
       url: me.url,
       dataType: 'json',
       cache:false,
       type: 'GET',
       data: function ( d ) {
          $.extend(d, me.data);
          d.supersearch = $('.my-filter').val();

          // Retrieve dynamic parameters
          var dt_params = $('#mytable').data('dt_params');
          // Add dynamic parameters to the data object sent to the server
          if(dt_params){ $.extend(d, dt_params); }
       }
    },
    columns: me.columns,
    columnDefs: me.renderer,
    initComplete: function() {

    }
 });
```

**Handle click event on a button:**

NOTE: I'm assuming that this is the only place where you would be adding dynamic parameters for AJAX call.

```
 $('.button').on('click', function(){
    // Set dynamic parameters for the data table
    $('#mytable').data('dt_params', { name: 'test' });
    // Redraw data table, causes data to be reloaded
    $('#mytable').DataTable().draw();
 });
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I tried to change me.data to table.data because me is out of scope, but no go.

Comment: what if i want the new parameter to be poasted as custom vm object as second parameter of action?

Answer (score 4):

My way is not so pretty, but very simple and works great: when I want to pass custom parameters while redrawing the DataTable, first I simply change its URL:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.url('/custom/path/with/custom/parameters/inside/');
$('#table_id').DataTable().draw();
```

Then, if necessary, as a first step of the "on draw.dt" event I change it back to the normal URL:

```
$('#table_id').on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.url('/normal/path/for/ajax/source/');
    // ...
)};
```

The only disadvantage of this approach that it needs some trick to squeeze those custom parameters into the alternative path. Besides, it needs some server-side work also to prepare that alternative route and to extract those custom parameters from it.

Comment: that solution is simple

Answer (score 1):

only one way worked for me.

```
function MyDataTable(myParam){
$('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();
if(!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#mytable')){
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bProcessing: true,
    paging: true,
     ajax: {
        url: me.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        type: 'GET',
        data: function ( d ) {
            $.extend( d, me.data);
            d.supersearch = myParam;
        }
    },
    columns: me.columns,
    columnDefs: me.renderer,
    initComplete: function() {

    }
});
}
}
MyDataTable(null); // initialize call
```

then, you can call DataTable function.

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  MyDataTable('test'); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GET, after init the datatable, you can use the function url and load to specify a different url

```
var table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
table.ajax.url( urlFiltros ).load();
```

Answer (score -1):

I got solution after return extend from function

```js
"ajax": {
  'type':'POST',
  'url': base_url+'/admin/get_common_search_modal',
  'data': function(data){
    return $.extend( {obj}, data, {
      primary_id: obj.default_primary_id,
      module_name: obj.search_module_name,
      whereNotColumns:obj.whereNotColumns,
      whereNotArr:obj.whereNotArr,
      whereArr:obj.whereArr,
      module_list_name:$('#search_modal #module_list').val(),
    });
  },
},
```