# Datatables 1.10 modify custom HTML param to send to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

How do I modify a custom HTML variable to send to the server after dataTables has been initialized?

I can send custom data using the `ajax` paramater before dataTables has been initialized.

I have a custom filter that I want to use add data to the request after dataTables has been initialized and then redraw the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) to specify a custom parameter sent to the server, see the example below.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.json",
        "data": function (d){
            d.example_select = $('#example-select').val();
        }
    }
});
```

`ajax.data` callback function will be called every time DataTables requests data from the server.

To reload data from the server after your filter changes, you can use [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) function, for example:

```
$('#example-select').on('change', function(){
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: The problem is adding the new ajax data once dataTables has already been initialized. The only way I could do it was to destroy the table and reinitialize it with the new ajax data. - Which the documentation states is bad for performance.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, you don't need to re-initialize the DataTables. `ajax.data` callback will be called every time data is requested from the server (via DataTables controls or `ajax.reload()` method), customize `ajax.data` function to send the parameter you need.

Comment: Attempting to modify the ajax data once it has been initialized, results in the alert popup with the message the dataTables has already been initialized.

Comment: If you're getting this message, most likely it means you're not using DataTables properly. Are you available to chat? Or give example of how you're using it, code sample would also help.

Comment: I'm just out but will be back online in an hour.

Comment: I was trying to do something like this: https://gist.github.com/asacarter/c05fa3b71f8a8bd6239e

Comment: I can see lots of methods in the API for getting the ajax data that was returned from the last request but I cant find a method to edit the data to be sent in the next request.

Comment: Added [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/2/) for demonstration on proper way to send extra parameter to the server.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly for my use case. However, if one wanted to add a new parameter to be sent to the server rather change the value of an existing one, how would one do that? - Just in case I need that for the future..

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28990562/3549014) to similar question that shows one of the possible solutions if number of parameters varies.